# Testing Google Analytics iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, ios, google-analytics

Has anyone found a good way to test Google Analytics on iOS? The SDK is really simple but the docs do not discuss how to test or validate.

Does the library behave differently on the simulator or when running a debug build config?

I setup a delegate GANTrackerDelegate with this delegate method:

```
- (void)trackerDispatchDidComplete:(GANTracker *)tracker
                  eventsDispatched:(NSUInteger)eventsDispatched
              eventsFailedDispatch:(NSUInteger)eventsFailedDispatch;
```

That method gets called just fine and I see positive values in eventsDispatched and eventsFailedDispatch has always been 0. Beyond that is there a way I can test that those events are being received correctly and correlate with what I think I'm submitting?

I'm thinking I need to setup a dedicated GA Website profile for test. Run a fixed set of UI automation unit tests and then wait 24 hours for that data to be available and validate "by hand". Ick.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Now it's a lot easier with realtime analytics, you see the visit in realtime, and it's working on the simulator :

https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#realtime

Comment: How long does this take to start working after creating the 'property'? I'm not seeing any traffic.

Comment: For me, it was nearly immediate

Comment: The link seems like web. Does this googles realtime analytics work on iPhone?

Comment: @neoneye yes, you can have stats on an iPhone app (just include the Google Analytics SDK in your app). And you can create a mobile App account.

Comment: is there any way to test the installs stats on development environment?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just test the lib separately? Write a simple class and make as many calls as you want. This won't involve any UI automation so should be easy to implement.

Comment: I'm not concerned about testing the lib. I need to test my interactions with it and my integration points. Let's say I have a UI automation test case that navigates through 5 views and 12 states within those views. I want to track 4 key points in GA an know that when test case X runs the events Y are correctly reported.

Answer (score 2):

[Mobile Analytics: An End-to-End Walkthrough](http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/analytics_end_to_end.html) has a section "Finding Data in the Analytics Web Interface" that says,

> Bear in mind that it can take the analytics front-end up to 24 hours to process newly collected data.

So it looks like setting up a dedicated GA Website profile for test and performing scripted UI tests is probably your best bet.

Comment: Yes unfortunately this seems to be the only thing that is possible to do. I noted the 24hr delay in my question. If you are looking at this issue please remember that traffic from the simulator will not be logged by the lib.

Comment: So to confirm. Traffic through the simulator will NOT be logged to your google analytics dashboard? @Nick And is it a 24hr delay for iphone Apps? My real time tab in GA hasn't shown any activity although I've ran the app on both the simulator and a device multiple times in the last hour.